# Create Cardview with inflater

Tags: android

Basically trying to create a cardview layout within my main activity which will inflate on touch and can also be edited while inflated and swipe away to delete.

Application purpose is to be like a note taking app which allows you to create notes using the FAB (already created). 
I am stuck trying to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a very old question, i created the cards dynamically using recyclerview and of course CardView, in depth documentation can be found here http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html 
and
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465